# clearing an setInterval in react by using a loading state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval, clearinterval

I am struggling with a simple timer here...I wam trying to count up when a query is running, then have it stop once the query is complete.

This is how I have currently set it up, but once the query has finished running the counter just continues to run even though `!loading`

```js
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(null)
  const [error, setError] = useState('')

  // Counter
  const [count, setCounter] = useState(0)

  const getPrestoData = async () => {
    setLoading(true)

    let count = 0

    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      count++
      setCounter(count)

      if (!loading) {
        clearInterval(timer)
      }
    }, 1000)

    await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/get-dspdaily/${dealId}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        setData(data)
        setLoading(false)

        setDealId('')
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        setError(error)
      })
  }
```

I have thought about putting the fetch statement inside `setInterval` but then it would be running every second which wouldn't be right.

I am sure this is pretty easy, but I can't figure out how to stop / pause the dam thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the interval callback is using the scoped `loading` variable at the time the callback function was created. So it will be a constant value.

You could clear the interval in the `.then` or `.finally` block of the `fetch`.

But even simpler would be to remove the interval completely and just use the [Performance API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance_API) and get the time before and after the `await`.

```
const start = performance.now();
await fetch(`http://127.......`).then(...);
const end = performance.now();
setCounter(end - start); // in milliseconds;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it was only a simple tweak for what i needed. I tried the performance API, that worked fine but It was a count after the completion. Where as i needed a count up...but setting the `clearInterval` in the `.then` worked...thanks